# Calling a Async method inside a for loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a model:

```java
package com.example.asyncmethod;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class User {

  private String name;
  private String blog;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getBlog() {
    return blog;
  }

  public void setBlog(String blog) {
    this.blog = blog;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User [name=" + name + ", blog=" + blog + "]";
  }

}
```

a service call like below

```java
package com.example.asyncmethod;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Service
public class GitHubLookupService {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GitHubLookupService.class);

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public GitHubLookupService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<User> findUser(Integer user) throws InterruptedException {
    logger.info("Looking up " + user);
    String url = String.format("https://api.github.com/users/%s", user);
    User results = restTemplate.getForObject(url, User.class);
    
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(results);
  }

}
```

Async runner class:

```java
package com.example.asyncmethod;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

@Component
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppRunner.class);

  private final GitHubLookupService gitHubLookupService;

  public AppRunner(GitHubLookupService gitHubLookupService) {
    this.gitHubLookupService = gitHubLookupService;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Start the clock
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // in real use case before the for loop I will have a database call to get the number of records and based on the size I need to call that many number of times.
for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++){
    CompletableFuture<User> page1 = gitHubLookupService.findUser(1);
   }

    // Wait until they are all done
    CompletableFuture.allOf(page1).join();

    // Print results, including elapsed time
    logger.info("Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    logger.info("--> " + page1.get());

  }

}
```

So in the above for loop, I might call the findUser as per the number of records returned by DB.

Also in the future I might need to add few more async calls like findOrders, findInventory, findAccess etc which will call another services over http.

Considering the async call may succeed for one record and fail for another record, how can I approach here to call the async in the best possible way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to realize complete advantage of Async calls, I will suggest to avoid using CompletableFuture.get() or CompletableFuture.join().

Using this calls blocks your main thread till the time all the tasks (as part of CompletableFuture.allOf() ) are completed.

Instead you can use various functions that are provided to run a Lamba function on completion of all the futures (Also allows to handle failure in any of the Future).

Please refer the Java Docs for more details and check which method is more convenient in your implementation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html